# openssh not requesting X11 forwarding

Tags: openssh

I can't see any message relating to X11 forwarding.
I am using windows 10 as a client and the Raspberry pi 4( debian buster) as a server

```
steven@DESKTOP-8EMNIS1 ~
$ ssh pi4 -Y -v
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to pi4 [fe80::b5d0:4a20:7aac:baea%3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspb
ian-10+deb10u2+rpt1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x0400
0000
debug1: Authenticating to pi4:22 as 'steven'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ubyhDQ0qt2j1WcMpHZlhbnGdzenQ
e6vf5ON+bm08LRI
debug1: Host 'pi4' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rs
a-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\steven/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. X11 forwarding, just like interactive shell or any other SSH channel, can only be requested **after** you have authenticated to the server – not before. Since your connections are interrupted before you log in, they never reach that point.

Comment: but it's not working see the above post for errors i get when i try running xclock

Comment: @ageis23 You substantially changed the question after receiving an answer. This is not nice. The answer answers the original question.